# Performing contract testing using Spring Cloud Contract against AWS API Gateway/Kinesis

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-contract

I want to perform contract testing on a REST API (using AWS API Gateway) that feeds events to Kinesis.  I've been looking at Spring Cloud Contract to perhaps perform this type of contract testing.  However, I cannot find anything online that uses Spring Cloud Contract to perform testing (as a Spring Cloud Contract server/producer in this case of Kinesis) of this type.  Is this even possible and/or does this even make sense using Spring Cloud Contract?  Should I use another tool to perform contract testing against AWS API Gateway/Kinesis?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question. Yes, you can perform it via the integrating with WireMock. Since you don't own the api of that application, you can't force them to create contract definitions and stubs etc. What you can do, however, is to set up tests that will call the real api of the aws gateway and will record the pair of request / reply in a form of a wiremock stub. Here you can find such an example for stubbing out the api of the company called Stripe https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/the-legacy-app/tree/master/stubs_with_proxy

Comment: I apologize for any confusion here and not being clear.  However, I actually would be the one creating the API of the application and handling the processing of API requests (i.e. not the client of the API gateway).  In Spring Cloud Contract terms, that would mean I would be the producer.  In this case, the API would be served using AWS API Gateway.  AWS API Gateway would be a proxy to pass in the events into Kinesis.  Hope that clears up my question - and I hope you will have an answer for testing on the Spring Cloud Contract producer side considering the use of AWS API Gateway and Kinesis.